# Internet explorer 8 cannot replace newline, while internet explorer 9, firefox and chrome can?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, newline

On my site I have a large number of images with accompanying text, sent from the server as php `json_encode($object)` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jsonimgs = '[["90","1","Foraeldreforeningens Chris McDonald-arrangement i aulaen ma. 10. oktober 2011 \nFotos: Silas Staal ","cmd13.jpg","15","0"],["91","2","Foraeldreforeningens Chris McDonald-arrangement i aulaen ma. 10. oktober 2011\nFotos: Silas Staal ","cmd1.jpg","15","1"],["92","3","Foraeldreforeningens Chris McDonald-arrangement i aulaen ma. 10. oktober 2011\nFotos: Silas Staal ","cmd2.jpg","15","2"]]';
   jsonimgs = jsonimgs.replace(/(\r\n)|(\n)/g, '<br />');
   var images = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonimgs);
</script>
```

This images object is used in javascript space to handle navigation between images.

As you an see i replace all newlines with a `<br>` tag, because otherwise an exception is thrown by the `.parseJSON` function, and the images variable is not created.

This works fine in internet explorer 9, latest version of firefox and google chrome. But when I try to run it in internet explorer 8, it does not work. My guess is that internet explorer 8 does not for some reason replace the newline tags, and that the `.parseJSON` function therefore does not work, and that the images variable therefore is not created.

So my question is: How can I ensure that the images variable is always created in all browsers, no matter what type of characters there might be in the `$images` variable sent from the server?

Kind regards.

Comment: I would do this replacement serverside.

Comment: I already tried this, but nl2br(); does for some reason not replace any of the linebreaks in the code?

Comment: jsonimgs is either a big string or you have pasted just part of your code... anyyways, sample data?

Comment: I have pasted an example above.

Comment: Alright i have found something really strange. When i try to simply remove the linebreaks from the json string manually on the backend, the script still does not work in ie 8. I get the error "Unable to get value of the property '1': object is null or undefined", which might indicate that the images variable is not set right? So i tried doing console.log(images), and i get the following: "90,1,Forældreforeningens Chris McDonald-arrangement i aulaen ma. 10. oktober 2011 <br>Fotos: Silas Staal ,cmd13.jpg,15,0,91,2 ...." notice how all the json formatting is gone? What is going on?

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected in IE 8 to me - http://jsfiddle.net/5pNHe/2/ . If you can edit that to reproduce the problem it would help.